# Why my UIScrollView not scrolling within this cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I'm building a UIScrollView inside a UITableViewCell so the cell can scroll left and right. I set the scroll view up in a storyboard without any AutoLayout constraints, and created an outlet for it. I put a UILabel inside the scroll view and then set the contentSize of the scrollview in code.

But when I run it in the simulator, I'm completely unable to scroll the cell left or right. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a little project I built showing it off in a simple case: http://cl.ly/0r2f0K1K3L1s

I'd include more code, but there's really not much more to it than what I outlined, as most of it is done in the storyboard. Is there something special to use storyboards and scroll views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a storyboard with auto layout turned on as the source of your prototype cell with the scroll view inside it. Hence your attempt to set the scroll view's content size manually is failing. Either use internal constraints to set the contents size, or else create and configure the scroll view and its contents entirely in code so that auto layout doesn't apply to them, or else use a separate .xib as the source of your cell (so that you can turn off auto layout there).

I was able to get your scroll view working using constraints in your storyboard. I had to give both the scroll view and the label appropriate constraints.

Comment: What would these constraints you set look like?

Comment: Do you understand how constraints work to set the content size of a scroll view?

Comment: The trailing right constraint from the label must be big, to make the scroll view scrollable to the left.

Comment: Ah ha. So I've recreated it [here](http://cl.ly/2E410n3o2i3e). I understand that the content size is deciphered from the subviews constraints within it. I cannot for the life of me seem to set desirable constraints, however. What I'm trying to do it have it be 960 pt wide so I can slide it all the way to the left or right. (960 = 3 * 320). No matter what constraints I put it seems to say that it's created an ambiguous content size for the scroll view... (Yes I'm trying to do it with a view so I can encompass the subviews cleanly, I hope that's not wrong.)

Comment: "an ambiguous content size for the scroll view" Let's say the label is the only thing inside the scroll view. Then you must have constraints from it to the scroll view on _all four sides_. You are describing the content size with those constraints. The one on the right must have its `constant` set to a big number even though there is not really room for that in the view, because you want to shove the content size off to the right so you can scroll left.

Comment: Or if your hierarchy is scroll view -> content view -> label, then you must do that with the content view. But in that case you must dictate _all four sides and the height and width_ of the content view, because unlike a label, it has no inherent size.

Comment: Download this example from my book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch07p367scrollViewInNibAutolayout/ch20p673scrollViewInNib It has _no code_ but it configures the scroll view completely in the storyboard, including the content size so that it is scrollable.

Comment: If you want to be able to scroll left, why would you push the content size right? Isn't that creating content size on the right that we can't see, so we'd scroll to it? And I think I understand what you're saying with a content view, and that example helped a lot, but take [this example I quickly created](http://cl.ly/3m022d0B160W). It's a pink contentview that I want to scroll left or right. I've seemingly set all the constraints I need, and set the height to be the same as the scroll view, but it still complains and starts off poorly positioned. What am I doing wrong it that project?

Comment: @Aloha64 if you will put your example on github instead, I'll fork it, try to fix it, and send you a pull request so you can examine the changes.

Comment: @Aloha64 Yes, exactly, you DO want to scroll to it! You want to scroll left, not right. So your content looks like this: |-label--------| The big space is on the right so the label can be *moved left*. The pipes are "edges" of the scrollable content. The space on the right must be wider than the distance to the edge of the scroll view, or the content will not be scrollable (that is how scroll views work!)

Comment: Oh, I totally understand now. I was messing up the directions in my head. Here's the GitHub repo: https://github.com/aloha64/ScrollableTableViewCell (Thanks so much.)

Comment: @Aloha64 No, I don't see anything. https://github.com/aloha64/ScrollableTableViewCell is essentially an empty project. It has no table views, no constraints, no nothing.

Comment: That's really embarrassing. Sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: Okay, @Aloha64, I've fixed up your example and created a pull request. Pull the changes and merge it in, and download and run the example. You will see that the sliding view is now slidable (and there is even a little surprise waiting for you when you do). No code was involved; all I did was tweak the storyboard a little.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's really awesome. Is it possible to get it to scroll both right *and* left though?

Comment: Yes, of course. Look at what I did on the right (trailing) and do that on the left (leading). Think about what I'm showing you and what I've been telling you.

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to this. Thanks so much, massive help and a phenomenal book.

Comment: Gah, last questions. Is there more to it than just making the leading constraint non-zero? If I increase it to add space to the other side it pushes the view off center. Lastly is it possible to not explicitly set the height, but have it equal to the scroll view's height?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still facing issue try this.

If you are using custom cell class

try

```
self.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

or

```
cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to Storyboard-> Remove using AutoLayout. Your cell can scroll. You dont set any constraint but system constraint will be fire in runtime.

Comment: What if I want Auto Layout for other cells?

Comment: turn on autolayout, find a effective way to set autolayout constaint to your cell. Asking other question and mark right anwser.